# Curl works on Windows Server but not on Linux. Is SSL to blame?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm using Amazon Linux. Curl works fine for most sites, but there is one particular site where nothing at all is returned. The exact same code works fine on a Windows server

The code is

```
$url = "https://www.example.com";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
```

I turned on `verbose` for the Linux machine which shows

```
NSS error -12273 (SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_READ)
```

This does not appear on Windows.

The Curl info for Linux is:

```
curl

cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.38.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  Yes
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI    No
TLS-SRP No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version NSS/3.16.2 Basic ECC
ZLib Version    1.2.7
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.2
```

and on Windows:

```
curl

cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.30.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  No
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI    Yes
TLS-SRP No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    i386-pc-win32
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1e
ZLib Version    1.2.7
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.2
```

Is there something different enough that would cause a difference in how Curl operates? I believe SSL is somehow the culprit here.

Thank you

Comment: Did you search SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_READ here?

Comment: Yes, but I only found issues from people who control the site and had user complaints. I don't have control over the site where I'm using curl.

Comment: This problem is probably specific for a site and a specific SSL backend. Your Windows version uses OpenSSL while the Linux version uses NSS as the backend. If you would show the site you are trying to access one could have a closer look.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I cannot do that. Should I switch the Linux to OpenSSL, how would I do that?

Comment: Anyone? I'm kind of at a loss here.